# Input focus in CkEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How do you focus a text input field in the content area of CkEditor? Calling `$(inputselector).focus()` doesn't seem to work. The cursor stays where it was.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think CKEditor has an iframe which contains those inputs. See if `$(inputselector)` return any collection of elements, and if it does, you might have to work around an event cancellation or something.

Comment: it picks up events that get triggered on the input but I can't get the element focus to happen, even if I trigger the event explicitly. I'm thinking that focus() doesn't actually move the cursor in this case.

Comment: That's browser behavior. Take out the `contenteditable` attribute and it should work. `$(inputselector).closest('body').removeAttr('contenteditable');` or wherever the `contenteditable="true"` is located.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. Still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get Google Chrome (just for this test)
2. open http://ckeditor.com/demo
3. hit `Ctrl+Shift+I` for Debugger
4. Click "Console" (last tab - it has a small Schweitzer and a tomato)
5. Copy and paste all the lines below and hit Enter

   ```
   var tgbody = $('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   var target = $(tgbody).find('> *')[0];
   var wildin = $("<input type='text' name='cfld' id='cfld' value='some text' />");

   $(tgbody).removeAttr('contenteditable');
   $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).removeAttr('contenteditable');
   wildin.appendTo(target);

   /// O.o 0.º

   wildin.focus();
   ```
6. Hit `Ctrl+Shift+I` again; you'll notice there's a new input inside the content area and your cursor is in it.
7. ?????
8. PROFIT

Comment: It looks like this method works in chrome but not firefox. I have been testing in firefox so that is why it hasn't been working.